# error: laravel Undefined variable at view controller

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I am having trouble with a view. This is my controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $images=ImageUpload::all();
    return view('index', compact('images'));
}
```

**The view:**

```
@foreach ($images as $image)
    <p>{{$image->title}}</p>
@endforeach
```

**My route:**

```
Route::post('upload','imageController@index');
```

**I have tried:**

```
   return view('index')->with('images', $images);
```

&

```
   return view('index')->with(compact('images'));
```

&

```
return view('index')->with(['image' => $image]);
```

**My error:**

> Undefined variable: images (View: C:\Users\Aioro\Desktop\webcomiclaravel\resources\views\index.blade.php)

Comment: the route you provided is irrelevant. and try `dd($images)` in your index function and check what you get.

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: This is likely a typo in copy/paste, but `->with(['image' => $image]);` definitely wouldn't work, the variable is `$images` (you missed the "s")

Comment: @zahidhasanemon is correct, $images is likely null

Comment: his route is posting to store. His first example is index... Question is if he's trying to load the view in store method, is there an images variable there?

Comment: Except no, `$images` being `null` isn't the same as an undefined error. Also, `ImageUpload::all()` cannot return `null`. It will return an empty `Collection` if nothing is found.

Comment: try after clear the route, view and config cache in laravel.

Comment: Your screenshot shows you're on `http:localhost:8000/`. You need to have a route `Route::get("/", "imageController@index");`, and the code you've posted should work just fine. Please add the results of `php artisan route:list` to your question, and check for any instances of `return view("index")` that doesn't include `compact("images")`, etc.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**in your ImageUpload Model**

you would also define

```
class ImageUpload extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'your table name';
    protected $fillable = [
        'title'
    ];
```

**In your controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $images=ImageUpload::get();
    return view('index', compact('images'));
}
```

**In your web.php**

```
Route::post('upload','imageController@index');
```

**in your index.blade.php**

```
@foreach ($images as $image)
    <p>{{$image->title}}</p>
@endforeach
```